# Como funciona as utilidades responsivas do Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3, layout-responsivo, grid

Do ponto de vista de performance da aplicação,
como funciona as classes `hidden-**` e `visible-**` ?

Se eu colocar uma div com `hidden-xs` ela será carregada em um dispositivo xs e não será visível, ou o bootstrap faz essa verificação antes de carregar - poupando recursos e dados da rede - ?

Comment: Na [source da versão 3](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L6538-L6540) só vi `display:none` sendo aplicado. O mesmo pra [versão 4](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L6204-L6294) (em desenvolvimento). Se essas classes fazem somente isso, só não vai deixar o navegador renderizar/mostrar o conteúdo, "por baixo dos panos" ele vai ser carregado normalmente. Como não uso esse framework não sei responder com detalhes, mas aparentemente não faz nenhuma mágica para poupar recursos. **:)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se você der uma olhada no css do bootstrap notará o seguinte código:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .hidden-xs {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .visible-xs {
    display: block !important;
  }
  table.visible-xs {
    display: table !important;
  }
  tr.visible-xs {
    display: table-row !important;
  }
  th.visible-xs,
  td.visible-xs {
    display: table-cell !important;
  }
}
```

Pelo que você pode ver não há muito segredo, as classes `visible-*` recebem `display: block` e as `hidden-*` recebem `display: none`, a diferença é a utilização de `@media` que verificam qual resolução especifica para ser acionado a classe.

Existe  também a classe `hidden`, que age em todas as resoluções.

Alguns exemplos de como elas são executadas:[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rLr6m42w/2/)